# How to set timeout for google api php client library

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I am using Google's [php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to build an app. Sometimes, Google takes up to 100 seconds to respond to an API request. I'd like to limit the socket timeout to 30 seconds.

Anyone know how this is possible? Not seeing any clear examples in the docs and I nothing timeout-related jumped out at me looking at the source.

I did find [this example](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors) in the docs for the Java client, but I can't seem to find the PHP equivalent.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it have to do with the Gmail API? Can't you just set a limit of 30 seconds on your end?

Comment: I'm using the php client library, so I'm not making any raw http requests, the library is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/612) you can pass parameters directly to curl.

```
$client->setClassConfig('Google_IO_Curl', 'options',
    array(
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10
    )
);
```

Comment: This answer is no longer valid and `setClassConfig` was deprecated in latest version.  See answer below

Answer (score 6):

In Google API v2 this can be done through the Guzzle client

```
$http = $googleClient->getHttpClient();
$http->setDefaultOption('connect_timeout', 10);
$http->setDefaultOption('timeout', 10);
```

Comment: This still works today for release 2.2.0 (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases)

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me on v2.2.2:

```
$client->setConfig('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT', 100); 
$client->setConfig('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', 1000);
```

Comment: How did you test to know that worked ? I see nothing via xdebug in guzzle object.

Comment: It gave me the desired output as the script executed completely in the time.

Answer (score 0):

For version `2.12.1`, looking at the Google Client Class, this wont work. Not sure about other versions.

`$client->setConfig()` - just adds the config to the $config property, its the same if you pass in the config in the constructor - `new \Google\Client(['CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' => 100]);`. The $config property will hold this value, but it is not passed onto the httpClient.

When the package creates a HttpClient in `createDefaultHttpClient()` -> https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/src/Client.php#L1182 -> it does pass on `base_url`, `defaults` etc depending on what version you have of Guzzle, but sadly, nothing to do with timeouts. So if your pass anything into the config related to timeouts, its just not going to be added to the HttpClient.

**Solution:**

Create a HttpClient class yourself, set the timeout and pass it in:

```
$this->client = new \Google\Client();
$httpClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['timeout' => 7.0]);
$this->client->setHttpClient($httpClient);
```

Hope this helps.