# How to set curl timeout in Google API PHP client version 2.2.2

Tags: php, google-api, google-apps, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to set the default curl timeout in the scripts I am using for batch updating users using directory api. Only a handful of users are added before the curl connection times out.

I have [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660589/how-to-set-timeout-for-google-api-php-client-library) but it doesn't work with the API v2.2.2

Can someone show me how to update the curl timeout settings using php?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
$groupEmail = "my group email";

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('my-config.json');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'));
$client->setSubject('user being impersonated');
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client); 

try {
    //try something

    for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++)
    {
        $addThese[] = "something".$i."@gmail.com";
    }   

    //EXECUTE ADDITIONS AND REMOVEALS
    $client->setUseBatch(true);
    $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);

    foreach($addThese as $addThis)
    {
        $member = new Google_Service_Directory_Member(array('email' => $addThis,
                                'kind' => 'admin#directory#member',
                                'role' => 'MEMBER',
                                'type' => 'USER'));
        $batch->add($service->members->insert($groupEmail, $member));
    }
    $result = $batch->execute();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do something about the error
    //echo "Error: $e";
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: Added the code as requested. I have redacted information pertaining to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$client->setConfig('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT', 100);
$client->setConfig('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', 1000);
```

have in mind that possible problem can be in their max execution time (which is if i good remember something between 3 and 5 mins)

Comment: On this page https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib search for "Requests are timing out when using the client library"...

Comment: I tried your code (with minor modification conforming to syntax) but it doesnt work. I think this is to set the execution time, not the curl timeout.

Comment: Read carefully... Google using Zend Http Client, this is http request timeout... check also zent http client docs https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.http.client.html check maybe your problem is not related to http timeout...

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be working but I need to test it a bit more to be able to confirm. Will get back to you soon. Thank you, Sinisa, for pointing in the right direction.  $client->setConfig('CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT', 100);
$client->setConfig('CURLOPT_TIMEOUT', 1000);

Comment: OK - so the records are being added but the problem is that not all records are added when the script executes. The $result array outputs the outcome but only a fraction of records (300 out of 1000) are being added. I am not sure what the problem could be? Any ideas?

Comment: Have in mind that there is also allowed execution time for google api commands (not sure exactly but it is something like 3-5 mins)... so if you exceed that time probably their script stop... if that's the problem i suggest sending 200 at once 5 times...

Comment: Thanks, Sinisa. It turns out that this was because I was sending more than 1000 requests per batch while 1000 is the limit as per the API documentation. Could you please edit your answer to it reflect the correct syntax that worked for me (see my comment) so I can accept it to close this question? Thank you for helping out.