# Are there any restrictions on using Google Directory API batch-updates feature?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I created a new group through Admin control panel and use [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert) to add new members in bulk, using batch-update, to the tune of 1000 users.

The documentation states that it should be valid.

> You're limited to 1000 calls in a single batch request. If you need to make more calls than that, use multiple batch requests.

The script ends without error, however not all users are showing. Sometimes 300 get added on each execution, sometimes 150. I have to refresh it again and then more members are being added in chunks.

I wanted to clarify from experts if there are ***any*** restrictions to this approach using API? For example, may be, you can't add more than X number of users to a newly created group and perhaps you have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: [docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch)  The user who you are logging in as must be the same for all batch items.   And i think that the call you are sending must also be the same you cant send updates and inserts in the same batch.    Have you tried sending fewer then 1000 i have never tried to fill the batch request.  I know that any items that fail will just not be added.

Comment: Could you add the batching code you are using?

Comment: Thanks, DalmTo. I have the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998625/how-to-set-curl-timeout-in-google-api-php-client-version-2-2-2

Comment: Please edit this question and include your code here.

Comment: I think this is what it is. My calls were more than 1000 per execution. As I reduced the max to 900, it worked like a breeze.

Comment: Google is not very good at exact numbers.   1000 is more of an estimate i bet.

Comment: I guess. Thank you for your help, @DaImTo! Please put in an answer so I can accept it. The solution is to follow the limit of 1000 calls as per the documentation. Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the documentation states a batch can contain a max of 1000 request however I recommend going a bit lower say 900

> You're limited to 1000 calls in a single batch request. If you need to make more calls than that, use multiple batch requests.